# remove UIGestures when leaving scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer

I am having problems with my UIGestures in my game
At the gamescene, they work perfect, but when I move to another scene the UIgestures keep active and if I use them(swipe) than it crashes.

I know I have to use willmovefromview method in Gamescene file but have been working 2 days on this and still not working..

here is my viewcontroller file: (see comments for the gesture functions and gesture recognizers)

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation


class GameViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{

//gesture functions
func swipedRight(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    let skView = view as SKView
    let gameScene = skView.scene as GameScene
    gameScene.swipedRight1(sender)
}
func swipedLeft(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    let skView = view as SKView
    let gameScene = skView.scene as GameScene
    gameScene.swipedLeft1(sender)
}
func swipedDown(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    let skView = view as SKView
    let gameScene = skView.scene as GameScene
    gameScene.swipedDown1(sender)
}
func swipedUp(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    let skView = view as SKView
    let gameScene = skView.scene as GameScene
    gameScene.swipedUp1(sender)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let skView = view as SKView
    skView.multipleTouchEnabled = false
    scene = GameMenuScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    //scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.ResizeFill
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true
    skView.presentScene(scene)

//Gesture recognizers
    let swipeRight:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedRight:"))
    swipeRight.direction = .Right
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    let swipeLeft:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedLeft:"))
    swipeLeft.direction = .Left
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

    let swipeUp:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedUp:"))
    swipeUp.direction = .Up
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)

    let swipeDown:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedDown:"))
    swipeDown.direction = .Down
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)    
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
}


override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

}

PS: My app is starting on a menuscene, and the swipes must only be active at the gamescene, so I think I have to use didmovetoview method as well.

and here are the didmovetoview method and willmovefromview method on my gamescene file:

```
  override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

}
override func willMoveFromView(view: SKView) {

}
```

Who is going to help me? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
override func willMoveFromView(view: SKView) {
   for recognizer in self.view.gestureRecognizers! {
       self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
   }
}
```

Comment: error: SKView? does not have a member named 'gestureRecognizers'

Comment: Use the same view you added the gesture recognizers to.

Comment: What do you mean? i added the gesture recognizers to my viewcontroller as you can see in the code in my post.

Comment: You cannot add gesture recognizers to a controller. You are adding them to a view. That's the same view you have to remove them from. In your code you are using `view`. You can also not use `gestureRecognizers` and use your own references to the recognizers instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
self.view.gestureRecognizers=nil;
```

It works for me.